# If Statement not registering in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why these if statements aren't working. I have tried setting the second one to else if as well and it's still not working.

Basically I want to the code to add 1 to the count variable whenever a button is pressed.  The problem is that even though the `count++` is working, the if statements aren't registering and I can just keep playing around in the `if (count== 0)` section.

```
var player = "X";
var comp = "O";
var count = 0;
console.log(count);


//Code for turn 1
if (count == 0) {

//Code for Div 1
$("#1").one("click", function(){
console.log("hit")
count++;
console.log(count)
if ( $('#1').children().length == 0 ){
  $("#1").append("<p>" + player + "</p>");
  $("#5").append("<p>" + comp + "</p>");
}
else {
  console.log("full");
}

});
//Code for Div 2
$("#2").one("click", function(){
 console.log("hit")
count++;
console.log(count);
if ( $('#2').children().length == 0 ){
  $("#2").append("<p>" + player + "</p>");
  $("#5").append("<p>" + comp + "</p>");
}
else {
  console.log("full");
}

});
if (count == 1){
 $("#2").one("click", function(){
count++;

if ( $('#2').children().length == 0 ){
  $("#2").append("<p>" + player + "</p>");
  $("#3").append("<p>" + comp + "</p>");
}
else {
  console.log("full");
}

})
 console.log(count);};
```

Comment: It's not the problem because you happen to be getting lucky with a jQuery quirk, but your ID selectors (`$("#1")` and such) are invalid. An ID selector cannot start with a literal digit. The only reason they're working is that it happens that jQuery optimizes that into a call to `getElementById`, but it's an invalid selector and will not work properly in CSS or as part of a compound selector (such as `$("#1 span")` to select `span` elements within your `id="1"` element). If you want to use an ID selector with an element, start it with a letter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ahh okay I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: No worries. `id` values used to be more restricted in HTML (in theory; in practice, browsers never cared), but HTML5 aligned the spec with browser implementation. I don't know *why* CSS ID selectors aren't allowed to start with a digit, it seems to just be arbitrary, like someone was thinking of them as identifiers in program code. But there we are... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any logic that needs to be executed on each click must be triggered by that click. Right now, the `if`s at the top level are only run **once**, not in response to clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$("#1").one`, which by definition only works once:

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The
>   handler is executed at most once per element per event type. ([source](http://api.jquery.com/one/))

Change all `.one`'s to `.on`.